# MongoDB How filtered by key array (not value)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have an array with user keys.

Users with id: array('111', '333');

I would get the following scheme only some fields (name) of users with those ids.

```
    {
        "_id" : "78787878",
        "users" : {
            "111" : {
                "name" : "William",
                "e" : "w@sas..."
                ...
            },
            "222" : {
                "name" : "Sarah",
                "e" : "s@sas..."
            },
            "333" : {
                "name" : "Marie",
                "e" : "m@sas..."
            },..
         },..
}
```

**My expected result would be something like this:**

```
{
            "_id" : "78787878",
            "users" : {
                "111" : {
                    "name" : "William",
                },
                "333" : {
                    "name" : "Marie",
                }
             }
    }
```

I tried with:

```
db.getCollection('instagram').find({'_id' : '78787878', 'users' : { '$in' : ['456726', '2945551665'] } }, { '_id' : 0, 'users.name' : 1 })
```

**How to make such queries? Can I do it with "findOne" or should be with "aggregate"?**

### EDITED (Problem continues):

According to comments if I modify the schema as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "78787878",
    "users" : [
        {
            "id": 111,
            "name" : "William",
            "e" : "w@sas..."
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "name" : "Sarah",
            "e" : "s@sas..."
        },
        {
            "id": 333,
            "name" : "Marie",
            "e" : "m@sas..."
        },..
     ]
}
```

If I use **$in** it return all... Why not the filter is applied?

```
$filter = array(111, 333);
$this->db->{$collection}->find(array('_id' => '78787878', 'users.id' => array('$in' => $filter)), array('users' => 1));
```

**users.id is Int32.**

Answer (score 1):

You might want to restructure your data like

```
{
    "_id" : "78787878",
    "users" : [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "name" : "William",
            "e" : "w@sas..."
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "222",
            "name" : "Sarah",
            "e" : "s@sas..."
        },
        {
            "id": "333",
            "name" : "Marie",
            "e" : "m@sas..."
        },..
     ]
}
```

then you can query it easily like

```
db.instagram.find({'users.id':{$in: ['111', '333']}})
```

Comment: I have applied the new schema but the query still does not work me.

Comment: have you tried it using the mongo shell? or other mongoDB client?

Comment: I tried the query also in "Robomongo" and the result is still not filtering. The query:

db.getCollection('mycollection').find({
    '_id' : '78787878', 
    'users.id' : {'$in' : [111, 333]},
},
{ 'users' : 1}
)

Answer (score 0):

With such schema where you have hash keys it would be pretty difficult to query unless you can change it so that the user ids are embedded in an array.

However, with such structure the only option available is through projection for you to get thedesired output. You would need a mechanism to to construct the projection as in the following query

```
db.instagram.find(
    { "_id": "78787878"}, 
    { "users.111": 1, "users.333": 1 }
);
```

This will produce the wanted output

```
{
    "_id" : "78787878",
    "users" : {
        "111" : {
            "name" : "William",
            "e" : "w@sas..."
        },
        "333" : {
            "name" : "Marie",
            "e" : "m@sas..."
        }
    }
}
```

So given the input array with the user ids that you only want projected, you can construct the projection document through JavaScript's **[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** function, which reduces an array to an object. 
Consider the following approach to create the above query:

```
var userIds = ['111', '333'],
    query = { "_id": "78787878"},
    projection = userIds.reduce(function(o, v, i) {
        o["users."+v] = 1;
        return o;
    }, {});
db.instagram.find(query, projection)
```

Comment: I have applied the new schema but the query still does not work me.

Comment: @ephramd To what schema did you change? The above query only works with the original schema that you had in the question.

Comment: I edited the question (at the end I point editing). I have tried to apply the simplest structure without hash keys.

Comment: @ephramd Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I use mongodb 1.6.12 and PHP 5.6.17